# How can i directly set a 'manual' foreign key using ORMLite on Android?

Tags: android, foreign-keys, ormlite

I'm facing a little problem using ORMLite. I'm sure it's a really simple problem, but can't find any solution yet.

Basically, i'm trying to create a foreign key to another object using directly its key.

The code looks normally should look like:

```
public class A { }

public class B {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    public A mA;
}
```

But i'm trying to do that (because A is too big to carry on everywhere; i only keep its ID)

```
public class A { }

public class B {
    @DatabaseField() // How can I do that?
    public long mA_Id;
}
```

Has anyone already succeeded doing that ? Ultimately, i would like to have the "on delete cascade" constraint.

Thanks!

**Edit**:

Tried with:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignColumnName = DatabaseContract.A._ID)        
public long mA_Id;
```

but it crashed with :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Field FieldType:name=mA_Id,class=B is a primitive class long but marked as foreign
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i'm trying to do that (because A is too big to carry on everywhere; i only keep its ID)

First off, as @vishalk mentions, ORMLite only keeps the id field of `A` in `B`.   When you retrieve a `B` it would construct a `A` but only the `id` field would be populated.

If, however, you just want to store the `id` field manually then you can certainly do that.  Right now ORMLite does not generate foreign key constraints so I'd just make it a `long a_id` and leave it at that.  Then it would be up to you to use the id to get the associated `A` instance when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
private A mA;
```

Internally, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) will store a `mA_id` field (maybe the string name) in the `A` table but you don't have to worry about that. Remember that when you query for a `B`, the `A` that is set on the `B` field will just have the id field set. To have ORMLite also lookup the account you will need to set the `foreignFieldAutoRefresh=true`.

As @colletjb pointed out, here is some documentation on this subject. We've spent a long time on the documentation so it should be helpful.

[Foreign objects](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object)
[Foreign auto refresh](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-refresh)

Also, there is some [example code about foreign fields](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreign).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but actually, when i do that, it crashes due to the fact i'm not using an object, but a primitive data. If a keep my object into B instead of it reference (long), i will have an assignation problem... I need to remove A from B and have only "long mA_Id" pointing to it (but i can't find a way to create the foreign key that way).

Comment: I think its not possible with OrmLite.